# Why doesn't Java's BigInteger class have a constructor capable of taking a numeric literal?

Tags: java, design, language-design, object-oriented-design

Why doesn't Java's BigInteger class have a constructor capable of taking a numeric literal? Every single time I use BigIntegers, and many times I merely think about them, I wonder this.

What reason could the designers of java have had to exclude one despite the overwhelming convenience of one should it exist?

Comment: Because you can easily call `toString` on an integral type? And doing so would require multiple overloads - one per integral type.

Comment: I think one constructor taking a long would suffice, since a numeric literal can automatically cast to a long.  Java will let you cast a type to a more *precise* (not efficient, derp) type implicitly.  It kind of makes sense for people who want to build one from a floating point type to have to at least cast it, but I don't see why we force people who want to make a biginteger with a value of `3` suffer.

Comment: @kevincline: I'm not saying remove the string constructor, I'm asking why there isn't a long one.

Answer (score 19):

The answer lies in the [JavaDoc of `BigInteger.valueOf(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf%28long%29):

> This "static factory method" is provided in preference to a (`long`) constructor because it allows for reuse of frequently used BigIntegers.

In other words: `BigInteger.valueOf(long)` does exactly what you ask the hypothetical `BigInteger(long)` constructor to do, except it is (or at least can be) slightly more efficient at it.